# Multiple dex files when adding AirPush library

Tags: airpush

After adding airpush library I got the error below. I am not doing any thing else just copy the jar file into libs folder in my project.

```
[2013-11-22 21:03:04 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define packet/name /BuildConfig;
[2013-11-22 21:03:04 - NewPrincessColoringGame] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define packet/name /BuildConfig;
```

Comment: If your problem is still not solved then plz paste your code sample here and i can help you out. I have very good idea of Airpush Ads.

Comment: Thanks Aditya, I had contacted to AirPush and they sent me sample codes to integrate, thanks a lot.

Comment: don't use AirPush!! they are a scam!! they never pay!! (to me and couple of buddies) or pay much less (google it!!)

Answer (score 0):

"Clean & Build" the complete project.

Comment: I think the problem is not that simple.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you have the same class included in different jars. I am guessing you are using also other libraries such as Google AdMob, Google play services, etc. 
So you may want to check all the libs you are using too see which one is conflicted with Airpush.